# Check if one list contains strings contained in another list

Tags: file-comparison

I have a list of strings, say file1.txt:

```
a
B
ccc
    D
   E
 f
```

and another list of strings, i.e. file2.txt:

```
    a x y z
  43 5 B aa_f
    <|ccc
 |D>
    E
                            FFF
```

I want to check, for each line, that file2.txt contains the trimmed string (so no whitespaces around) contained in the respective line of file1.txt.
For example, line 2 in both files contains `B`, so this test should evaluate to `true`. However, the last line in both files are not in the substring relation, since file1.txt contains `f` and file2.txt does not have any `f` character in that line.

Comment: Does the second file contain `ccc` or `D`, or are you only interested in strings delimited by whitespace?

Comment: Are all strings in file1.txt free from "internal" whitespace?

Comment: So you want as a result a file of five line `true` and one line `false`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have no whitespace contained in your strings in `file1.txt`, the following `awk`-based approach should work:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{patterns[FNR]=$1} FNR<NR{if (index($0,patterns[FNR])>0) print "true"; else print "false"}' file1.txt file2.txt
```

For your example, this will yield

```
true
true
true
true
true
false
```

Some explanation: We use `awk` to read in both files, but process them in a different way.

- While processing `file1.txt`, indicated by `FNR`, the "per-file line counter", being equal to `NR`, the global line counter, we simply register all (trimmed) strings (`$1`, which is the first whitespace-delimited field of the line) in an `awk`-internal array, with the line number as index (note that these start with 1).
- While processing `file2.txt` (`FNR` is now smaller than  `NR`), we use the `index` function to look for the string `patterns[FNR]` in the entire input line (`$0`). If so, `index()` will return a start position larger than 0, and we print `true`, otherwise we print `false`.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'ARGIND == 1 { a[NR]=$1;     next }
     $0 ~ a[FNR] { print "true"; next }
                 { print "false"      }' ex1 ex2
```

In Awk, I prefer to write programs in a more "cond {action}" structure. This is very
similar to @AdminBee solution.

- `ARGIND ==1` - if this is the first argument: save the first word
- `$0 ~ a[FNR]`- if this line (`$0`) contains the saved homologous word, "true"; else "false"